# Phonegap: Upload in separate function

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to create a data capture form in phonegap.

This will consist of a few text input areas and a photo (along possibly with a signature).

I want all of this data to be sent off to the same PHP file at the same time so that the text data in the database and the image file name has the same timestamp as a reference.

I've managed to get the camera to take a photo and upload but I don't want the camera to upload straight away. I want the photo to sit in local memory until I press a button that fires off a function to upload the photo and send the text data at the same time.

Any help would be great

Comment: Sorry for the bump but does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To tell phonegap to select a file and make it sit there until you decide to upload it, I would do something like this.

```
//WITH THIS FUNCTION YOU CAN SELECT A FILE IN YOUR GALLERYfunction album_pic() { 
pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, function(ex) {
        alert("No file selected"); }, 
        { quality: 30, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
    mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA });}

//IF THE ALBUM FILE SELECTED IS SUCCESSFULfunction onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
console.log("* * * onPhotoURISuccess");

console.log(imageURI);    //imageURI IS THE FILE PATH OF WHAT YOU SELECTED

if(imageURI.indexOf('video') == -1){
    //IT'S A PICTURE
//do something with "imageURI"
}
if(imageURI.indexOf('video') !== -1){
    //IT'S A VIDEO
    //do something with imageURI
}}
```

Now you can create your upload() function and decide whenever you wanna send the file.